# Split and concatenate values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two different tables as below and have specific requirement of a sql query.

```
Table1:
Name   RuleNumber
Tom    1,2
Pete   1,3

Table2:
RuleNumber  Description
1           Rule1
2           Rule2
3           Rule3
```

How can I get a sql query result something like below

```
Name    Description
Tom     Rule1, Rule2
Pete    Rule1, Rule3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first need a custom split function to seperate the delimited list, and then use `FOR XML PATH` to combine the descriptions.  Here is your final query

```
select  t1.Name,
        STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Description
                FROM    table2 AS t2 
                WHERE   t2.ruleNumber in (select s from dbo.fn_split(t1.RuleNumber, ','))
        ORDER BY ruleNumber
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as 'Description'
from    table1 t1
```

Here is the code for the split function.

```
create function [dbo].[fn_Split]
(
    @String     varchar(8000) ,
    @Delimiter  varchar(10)
)
returns @tbl table (s varchar(1000))
as

begin
declare @i int ,
    @j int
    select  @i = 1
    while @i <= len(@String)
    begin
        select  @j = charindex(@Delimiter, @String, @i)
        if @j = 0
        begin
            select  @j = len(@String) + 1
        end
        insert  @tbl select substring(@String, @i, @j - @i)
        select  @i = @j + len(@Delimiter)
    end
    return
end
```

Comment: Awesome. I just tried this and it actually brought back exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help!  That little split function can come in quite handy; I've used it for years.

Answer (score 0):

How the Table1's RuleNumber has more than one value? Is it a string? I will assume it is :

```
Name / RuleNumber
Tom  / 1
Tom  / 2
```

Then, the query would be:

```
select
  Name,
  ( 
     select Description 
     from Table2 as t2 
     where t1.ruleNumber = t2.ruleNumber
  ) as Description
from 
  table1 as t1
```

Comment: Sorry, This is just similar to JOIN and it doesn't achieve the result. Because the values in Table1 are comma separated multiple values. And in Table2 they are unique.